# TableLayout columns do not Resize

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a tableLayout with Three Columns.
Column 1 : A ListBox that is Dock->Fill
Column 2: a Button
Column 3: Another ListBox that is also Dock->Fill

For the resizing I have set all the columns to "AutoFit"
But when I resize the form, it only resizes the ListBox that I have in Column3 and it does Not resize the listBox in Column 1...so what is the problem? How should I set the properties so that with resixing the form, ListBox 1 and listBox2 both get resized but the Button keeps its design time size and does not get larger or smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved that. : Setting COL 1 and COL3 to "%50" and COL 2 to "AutoSize" fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of AutoSize set the columns to be Percent, with 3 columns each one will need to be 33.33%.  I tried this in a quick winForms app and was able to resize all 3 columns correctly.